# PATH is not permanently stored in file

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I want to add some variables to my `PATH` - I am using the following steps:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type the following commands:

   ```
   export GOROOT=/home/linux/go/hg
   export GOOS=linux
   export GOARCH=386
   export GOBIN=/home/linux/go/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
   ```

When I type the following command in a terminal window:

```
env | grep '^GO'
```

It shows:

```
GOBIN=/home/linux/go/bin/
GOARCH=386
GOROOT=/home/linux/go/hg
GOOS=linux
```

I have tried the following command in a terminal window:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and pasted the following lines at the end of the file:

```
GOROOT=/home/linux/go/hg
GOOS=linux
GOARCH=386
GOBIN=/home/linux/go/bin
```

The problem is that `env` is not showing the above mentioned variables in `PATH`. Perhaps  I am using the wrong command to store the paths, or storing my path variables in the wrong file?

Can someone guide me where and how to store the above mentioned variables in the `PATH` permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to export them.  Edit your `~/.bashrc` to something like this:

```
export GOROOT=/home/linux/go/hg
export GOOS=linux
export GOARCH=386
export GOBIN=/home/linux/go/bin
```

If you want the `GOBIN` available in your search paths, append this line too:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to export the variables in .bashrc as well.  Also, you might need to source .bashrc or log out and back in again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put `export` before the variables in your .bashrc.
2. Save the file.
3. Log in and out / Open new terminal.
4. Try for example `env | grep 'PATH'` and your path will show up.

Comment: The `env | grep '^GO'` is 100% valid regarding to what the op wanted to do.

Comment: Yes, and for that I edited my answer even before your comment.

Comment: Sorry, but my browser didn't reload.  :P